# Unpermitted parameters for post_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

So I am trying to make my topic controller create a new topic with an initial post. My new topic view looks like this

```
<% @title = "New Topic" %>

<h1>New Topic</h1>

<%= form_for [@topic.forum, @topic] do |f| %>

  <%= render "topic_form", f: f %>

<%= f.submit "Create Topic", class: "btn btn-primary" %>

<% end %>
```

Here is the partial as well

```
<% if @topic.errors.any? %>
<div class="alert alert-danger"> 
<p>The form contains <%= pluralize(@topic.errors.count, "error") %>.</p>
</div>
<ul>
  <% @topic.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
  <li class="text-danger"> <%= message %> </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
<% end %>

<div class='form-group'>
  <%= f.label :title, "Title*" %>
  <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control' %>
</div>

<%= f.fields_for :posts do |post| %>
  <div class='form-group'>
  <%= post.label :content, "Content*" %>
      <%= post.text_area :content, size: "50x6", class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Topic Model**

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :forum
 belongs_to :user
 has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy

 validates :title, presence: true

 accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts, allow_destroy: true

end
```

**Topic Controller**

```
def new
  forum = Forum.find(params[:forum_id])
  @topic = forum.topics.build
  post = @topic.posts.build
end

def create
  forum = Forum.find(params[:forum_id])
  @topic = forum.topics.build(topic_params)
  @topic.last_poster_id = current_user.id
  @topic.last_post_at = Time.now
  @topic.user_id = current_user.id
  if @topic.save then
    flash[:success] = "Topic Created!"
    redirect_to @topic
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

**With the strong parameter thing**

```
def topic_params
   params.require(:topic).permit(:title, :post_attributes => [:id, :topic_id, :content])
end
```

But no matter what I do it breaks. The development log says that there is

```
Unpermitted parameters: posts_attributes
```

I have searched online for countless hours and to no prevail. Anyone have any ideas how to fix this. Right now when I click the submit button in the Topic New View it submits with the title but the content you put in is lost and when I create a new post it works just fine and prints out the content the user puts in. So it only breaks when a new topic is created and the only part that breaks is the content part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be submitting `posts_attributes` (note the **s** after post). The parameter you defined is called `post_attributes`.

Comment: I think that actually fixed the problem but quick question it breaks because my view requires a user_id to access the username. How come when I do `params.require(:topic).permit(:title, :post_attributes => [:id, :user_id => current_user.id, :topic_id, :content])` that doesn't work?

Comment: I need to somehow link up a user_id to the initial post. Any ideas?

Comment: I think i figured it out. In the create method i just did a janky setup where @topic.posts[length].user_id = current_user.id. If you have any better ideas on how to fix this be my guest.